# Is it possible to open a pdf whilst it is being downloaded?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

Does anyone know if you can start displaying a pdf document in iOS before it has finished downloading? I know PDF supports this but can it be done in iOS?

I am wondering if something can be done with CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider and a custom provider, but I can't find much useful information on CGDataProviders.

Any ideas?